# Multiple files upload with vue axios and PHP - only one file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, file-upload, axios

I'm trying to create a multiple file upload using vue and axios. My problem is that Only ine file will be uploaded to the server. Here is the code I' using:
Template code

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple ref="images" @change="handleUpload()">
```

JS code

```
//this is part of the handleUpload() vue method.

let formData = new FormData();

for(let i;i < $refs.images.files.length; i++){
 let file = this.$refs.images.files[i];
 formData.append('image', file);
}

axios.post('/upload', formData, { header: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
.then( (response) => console.log(response, response.data) )
.catch( (error) => console.log(error) );
```

PHP server code

```
// I'm using slim 4 and sirius upload to manage the file validation/upload
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Sirius\Upload\Handler as UploadHandler;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->post('/platform/api/v1/compress', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    $uploadHandler = new UploadHandler('/uploads');
    
        $uploadHandler->addRule('extension', ['allowed' => ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']]);
   
        $result = $uploadHandler->process( $request->getUploadedFiles() );
        
        // handle single input with single file upload
        if( $result->isValid() ){
            $result->confirm();
                   
            $url = ["master_image_url" => "/uploads/".$result->name];

            $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($url));
        }


    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

How I can upload multiple files?Maybe I need to modify the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing "image" for "image[]" in the `append` function

Example:

```
for(let i;i < $refs.images.files.length; i++){
 let file = this.$refs.images.files[i];
 formData.append('image[]', file);
}
```

in server

```
$uploadedFiles=$request->getUploadedFiles();
foreach ($uploadedFiles['image'] as $uploadedFile) {
        if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to test but I think that the problem is also with the server side code?not sure about

Comment: I think you should add foreach $request->getUploadedFiles()

Comment: I'm not sure about this, slim will provide a `UploadedFileInterface` object that will contain uploaded files. The Sirius library that I'm using to manage the upload process will accept and handle the PSR-7 UploadedFileInterface object, maybe there is some function that will handle multiple files but I'm not sure